# How do I find my app in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

After a long time in Beta, my app is now ready for publishing. I published it about an hour ago. It is named Colors, a very short and often used name. So that is also the title in Google Play. But now when I search for Colors my App isn't shown when I search for Colors (not in all findings (about 100)). It is there because when I also search with the developer name it comes up at place 8 or so. What to do now? Change the name or add something in it?

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps to find your app:

1. Go to the app console at https://play.google.com/apps/publish
2. Choose your app
3. Hover the icon with the "I" letter in the circle beside your app name
4. Click "View in the Play Store"

Note, that your app needs to be published (as on the attached screen).

Moreover, your app may not be published immediately and probably you need to wait about a few hours until your app will be officialy available in Google Play Store.

It may be not so easy to find your app via search if it has popular or common name. I such case, Google algorithms may adjust search results depending on a different criteria. When your app is new, it may not be recognizable in the beginning.

[image: google play console]

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: If you published your app a short time ago, it is going to rank lower in searches. Give it a while, because the search feature is like google: It shows the most popular links with the same name first. It is the same thing with apps: The most popular with a given name rank first. FOr new apps, even when searching that name, similar names will rank higher because your app is newer.

Writing

```
pub:[Your Dev Name Here]
```

(without the brackets)

will show only the apps published by you. No space between `:` and the first letter in the developer name.

TL:DR;

The more downloads your app gets, the higher it will rank in searches. Changing the app name is not a good idea, as you will then take another long while to rank in the search for the new app name. Maintain the current name, make it good so it drives installs and it will rank higher eventually

### NOTE

It takes hour before the app shows in the search results. Meaning as you posted your app one hour ago, it will not rank for another day or so(in my experience). Getting it on top when there are many apps with similar names is even harder. But what you are experiencing is the time between your app being published and it showing in the search results.

Answer (score 1):

No One knows search algorithm parameters except people at Google.

But there are a lot of articles with suggestions, and what parameters influence to the position in Google Play. First of all this is popularity of your app, its score, etc. So changing app name won't affect, while you have few downloads.

For instance, I uploaded an app, named TurtleInfo. I haven't seen apps with the same name, but as soon as my app is too specific and has less than 50 downloads, Google Play search displays my app on position about 20. The apps, that goes before, just different games about Turtles, that has much more downloads than mine.

So if you wanna see your app first in search result on Google Play, you have to make it high-quality and really popular!

Comment: I just want to see it in about top 20 when you exactly search by the game name

Comment: There is no direct way to force your app to top 20 search results by some name. 
If people will download and rate your app high, somewhen you'll see it in top 20. Otherwise you won't.

Answer (score 0):

Link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your_package_name&hl=en

write your package name in front of id. and you'll get your app